# Angularjs calling clearfixes based on screen size with ng-if

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ng-if

I want my columns to display in 3 columns per row on medium and larger screen sizes (col-md-4), 2 columns per row on smaller screen sizes, and 1 column per row on extra small (col-sm-6), but when I view my app on my tablet, I get floating columns in the 2 column rows. I know its possible to use a clearfix class with ng-if to tell it to make a column every so many rows, but if I use:

`<div class='clearfix' ng-if='$index % 2 == 0'>`

it will make my columns create a new row every 2 columns, even on larger screens, which isn't what I want. Is it possible to make ng-if only add the clearfix after 2 columns strictly on the col-sm class, and not on the col-md class?

Comment: doing this in angular instead of responsive css would be horrible performance, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by listing to window `resize` event, Based on the screen inner width you can attach or detach the `div.clearfix` to the dom using `ng-if`.

EX:

**Controller:**

*maintain a variable to represents the window width `$scope.windowWidth`*

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
  $scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;

  $window.onresize = function(event) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    });
  };
});
```

**View:**

*Attach the div **IF** windowWidth <= 768 **ELSE**  Remove the div from the DOM.*

```
<div class="tab-only clearfix" ng-if="windowWidth <= 768">
  This will show only on min-width : 768px
</div>
```

here is a [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/E9iHzCNfLOOHlOW8WHE4?p=preview)

**`Please search for if there is any css fixes for this.`**

Comment: What is the `tab-only` class for? Is it just for demonstration purposes? I would replace that class with clearfix to get the results I'm looking for, correct?

Comment: I used that `tab-only` class only for css style purposes :), And yes, your correct you can replace it with `clearfix `, I'll update the answer.

Comment: A few problems here. Problem number one, my linter gives me an error telling me `'event' is defined but never used` and second of all, using the exact code you posted above wouldn't work because it will add a clearfix after every column when I wanted to add a clearfix after every two....So I ignored the linter error for now and tried to do it this way, and it didnt work:


    `<div ng-if='windowWidth <= 768'>
       <div class='clearfix' ng-if='$index % 2 == 0'>
       </div>
     </div>`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get my can't get my code to format properly in comment, it's ignoring all of the indents.